# C# SQL Data Mapping into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, mapping, sql-insert

I have a massive amount of data columns in a certain table an now need to map these into C# Visual Studio. Is there an easy way of doing this or is it still a laborious manual task. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
string query = @"UPDATE Buyer 
                SET DealID = @DealID,Title=@Title,FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,
               IDNo=@IDNo,Address=@Address,POAddress=@POAddress,HomeTel=@HomeTel,
               WorkTel=@WorkTel,Cell=@Cell,Fax=@Fax,Email=@Email,
               MarritalStatus=@MarritalStatus,SpouseFirstName=@SpouseFirstName,
               SpouseLastName=@SpouseLastName,SpouseWorkTel=@SpouseWorkTel,
               SpouseCell=@SpouseCell,SpouseFax=@SpouseFax,Notes=@Notes,
               id=@id,DealID=@DealID WHERE IDNo = @IDNo";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
string id = iDNoTextBox.Text;
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealID", txtDealNo.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", iDNoTextBox.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", titleComboBox.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstNameTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: There are numerous [ORM (Object Relational Mapper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) around that could remove this problem. Of course you need to dedicate a bit of your time to learn what is the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have some choices to do it in simple way

First : Use ORMs such `EntityFramework`, for example you can use `dapper-dot-net`, sample code:

```
var dog= connection.Query("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new {Age = (int?)null,Id=guid});
```

Insert example:

```
connection.Execute(@"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b)",
    new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }
  ).IsEqualTo(3); // 3 rows inserted: "1,1", "2,2" and "3,3"
```

Second: Use Array of type `SqlParameter` and insert that into `SqlCommand`

```
SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand("Command text", new SqlConnection("Connection String");
SqlParameter[] param = {new SqlParameter("@Name","Value"), 
                        new SqlParameter("@Name","Value"),
                            ........
                            };
Comm.Parameters.AddRange(param);
```

Third: Or write a good `Sql Assistant` and make a generic mapper for `object-to-relational` and vice versa. then you can produce your parameters at run-time and dynamically without hard coded.